# Dynamically accessing columns with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to dynamically taking the mean of a column using `dplyr`. From this site https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html I learnt that it should be possible as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(column=c(1,2,3))

column_string <- "column"
variable <- enquo(column_string) 
print(variable)
```

Output:

```
<quosure>
  expr: ^"column"
  env:  empty
```

And then:

```
df %>% summarise(mean=mean(!! variable))
```

Output:

```
  mean
1   NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(~"column") :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

The expected outcome is a data frame with value 2 of course. What am I missing? I suspect that it has something to do that the environment of the quosure is `empty`.

Comment: I realize this isn't the real question, but FYI for this specific example, there's always `df %>% summarise_at(column_string, mean)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would work:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(column=c(1,2,3))

column_string <- "column"
variable <- sym(column_string) 
print(variable)

df %>% summarise(mean=mean(!! variable))
```

`Enquo` is more suitable when you are referencing the columns which are unquoted (for example when writing functions), you can access the quoted ones with `sym` or `syms`.

Note that `sym` comes with `dplyr`, but you could do also without this with `as.symbol`.

An example of when `enquo` could be used:

```
summarise_mean <- function(df, col) {

  variable <- enquo(col)

  df %>% summarise(mean = mean(!! variable))

}
```

Output:

```
summarise_mean(df, column)

  mean
1    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use simple usage `as.symbol`

```
df %>% summarise(mean=mean(!! as.symbol(column_string)))
```